# javascript to regex to just keep letters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have tried to write the regex to remove all white spacing, special charcters, numbers from a string and just leave the letters.

For example, if I had the string

`3388@accffiillnnoooorrsttttttuy` I would want the following to be returned:

`accffiillnnoooorrsttttttuy`

I thought this would work but for some reason it doesn't appear to be doing what I expect

```
var letterPattern = /[a-zA-Z]+/g;

var string = string.match(letterPattern)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
var letterPattern = /[a-zA-Z]+/g;
var matches = '3388@accffiillnnoooorrsttttttuy'.match(letterPattern);
var string = matches[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is correct, the usage of `match` is incomplete though.

```
var letterPattern = /[a-zA-Z]+/g;

var matches = string.match(letterPattern);

if (matches) {
    string = matches[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following Regex

```
var string = "3388@accffiillnnoooorrsttttttuy";
string.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/gi,'');
```

Answer (score 0):

Check it:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Parse the String</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "3388@accffiillnnoooorrsttttttuy"; 
    var patt1 = /[a-zA-Z]/g;
    var result = str.match(patt1);
    var resultString = result.join("");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = resultString;
}
```